# ffmpeg doesn't output truehd audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some m2ts files with 7.1 truehd. When I attempt to concat them and use -c copy or if I use -acodec copy and put them in a m2ts output, I get no sound. I can also simply try a single file, not merging with anything, copy audio and video and output to another m2ts file, I still get no audio. ffpmeg sees the audio file and acts like it is copying it but it isn't there in the final product. Can ffmpeg not output truehd?

```
C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>ffmpeg -i 01.m2ts -c copy out.m2ts
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-12-675bb1f Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.100 / 56. 42.100
  libavcodec     58. 75.100 / 58. 75.100
  libavformat    58. 41.100 / 58. 41.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mpegts @ 000001ead9788a80] start time for stream 3 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 000001ead9788a80] start time for stream 4 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 000001ead9788a80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000001ead9788a80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from '01.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:06:30.27, start: 11.650667, bitrate: 35679 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:2[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)
    Stream #0:4[0x1201]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)
Output #0, mpegts, to 'out.m2ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 9357 fps=1026 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1619640kB time=00:06:30.26 bitrate=33997.7kbits/s speed=42.8x
video:1428645kB audio:117099kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.780587%

C:\Users\Michael\Videos\Recode>
```

Comment: Share full log of a basic attempt with one input

Comment: As requested... sorry it took so long.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is old. [Update](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) before doing anything else and try again.

Comment: I updated but the issue persists. Oddly, if I do a copy to mkv, I still have the audio but if I copy that back to m2ts, it is gone again. I've replaced the code in the original post with the new code.

Comment: How are you verifying that there is no audio in the resulting file?

Comment: I open its properties and see it listing no data rate on audio but 2 (only 2) channels. When I attempt to play the file regardless of player, there is no sound. The original plays just fine.

Comment: Here is data from an encode and from the output file:
 Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
    Stream #0:2[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
After:
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Unknown: none ([131][0][0][0] / 0x0083)
DVDFab says audio is "Und MP3FLOAT/"
I'm also noticing that files that used to encode fine no longer do. Some come out with MP2 audio others come out with Stream #0:2[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 0 channels, fltp instead of 5.1 channels.